# Invalid Query: Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count At Row 1 " error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

### Table structure for table `site`

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `site_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `adresa` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `oras` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telefon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `site`

```
INSERT INTO `site` VALUES (1, 'company LLC', 'address   ', 'city, KS', 'zip ', '(111) 111-7338', 'sales');
```

Comment: Whenever you use `insert`, always use an explicit column list.  This is a very good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing apostrophes between city and KS, you have:

```
'city, KS'
```

where as it should be

```
'city', 'KS'
```

As there are a different number of columns because of the typo the database server can't do an insert without explicitly named columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO `site` VALUES (1, 'company LLC', 'address', 'city', 'KS', 'zip', '(111) 111-7338', 'sales');
```

Problem came from your `'KS'`  and `'city'` without a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **ALL** the relevant columns in the `INTO` clause.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (list, of, columns)
  VALUES (set, of, values)
```

You appear to be using an `auto_increment` field, so this should be omitted from your field list as it's value is derived by the database internally.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
INSERT INTO `site`( `id` ,
  `site_name` ,
  `adresa`,
  `oras`,
  `stat`
  `zip`,
  `telefon`,
  `email`) VALUES (1, 'company LLC', 'address', 'city', 'KS', 'zip', '(111) 111-7338', 'sales');
```

**On a side note:-** *Always try to mention the column names while inserting. Its considered a good practice.*

Comment: Single quote is also missing after `city`:)

Answer (score 0):

just change some of the values inside, it corresponds to whatever value you want to put in that kind of data, you dont need to put the id because it is already auto incremented

```
INSERT INTO `site` VALUES ('site_name', 'addressa', 'oras', 'stat', 'zip', 'telephone', 'email');
```